# How to use PyQt5 .ui with PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt5

How can I use Qt's OpenGLWidget in my python application if I created the interface in Qt Designer?

Comment: @voiDnyx Well, yes. Anything wrong with this ? It took me quite a while to figure this myself, and i haven't found similar questions so i thought it might be useful for someone if i post this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have installed PyOpenGL, PyQt5, Qt5 editor (we don't need IDE, but we need Qt Designer that comes with it)

Using QtDesigner create .ui file with all necessary controls and OpenGL widget (name widgets appropriately, because in python you will use this name to access widget's objects)
Name this file test.ui and place it in the same directory as you .py file
You OpenGL widget has to be named "openGLWidget"

```
import OpenGL.GL as gl
import OpenGL.GLU as glu
import OpenGL.GLUT as glut
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qWidget
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qCore
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys
import os


class mainWindow(qWidget.QMainWindow):
    """Main window class."""

    def __init__(self, *args):
        """Init."""
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(*args)
        ui = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.ui')
        uic.loadUi(ui, self)

    def setupUI(self):
        print("\033[1;101m SETU6P UI \033[0m")
        self.windowsHeight = self.openGLWidget.height()
        self.windowsWidth = self.openGLWidget.width()

        self.openGLWidget.initializeGL()
        self.openGLWidget.resizeGL(self.windowsWidth, self.windowsHeight)
        self.openGLWidget.paintGL = self.paintGL
        self.openGLWidget.initializeGL = self.initializeGL

    def paintGL(self):
        self.loadScene()
        glut.glutWireSphere(2, 13, 13)

    def initializeGL(self):
        print("\033[4;30;102m INITIALIZE GL \033[0m")
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_BLEND)
        gl.glBlendFunc(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    def loadScene(self):
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        x, y, width, height = gl.glGetDoublev(gl.GL_VIEWPORT)
        glu.gluPerspective(
            45,  # field of view in degrees
            width / float(height or 1),  # aspect ratio
            .25,  # near clipping plane
            200,  # far clipping plane
        )

        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()

        glu.gluLookAt(12, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)


app = qWidget.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = mainWindow()
window.setupUI()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

At this moment you should see GUI windows with all elements you placed and openGLwidget with white sphere displayed in the center
Now you can use all OpenGl instrumentary to create your own 3D application.
For mouse input and interactions you can use Widget functions from Qt5
If you need to use Qt5 event you should use "on_widgetName_clicked" for defining new function in mainWindow class. It will act whenever this event is occured in GUI
PyOpenGl functionality is 100% accesible in this template, and you can use tutorials dedicated for default version (C/C++) as well without any issues

[Python code](https://pastebin.com/we0rDYcZ)
[.ui file code](https://pastebin.com/QspLi4t8)

Save .ui file as test.ui